# Combining data using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have some code that combines two arrays with an identifier array called `seqNum2`. I can't quite get it to combine a third array using Linq. The third array in my code would be `grossNGL2`. When I take `grossNGL2` out of the equation it does work, but I need to be in there. Here's the code:

```
private void grossOilMboeRadBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("testUltOilMBOE.txt"))
    {
        var items = grossOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (goil, seq) => new { GOIL = goil, Seq = seq }); //goil STANDS FOR GROSS OIL
        var items2 = grossGas2.Zip(seqNum2, (ggas, seq) => new { GGAS = ggas, Seq = seq }); //ggas STANDS FOR GROSS GAS
        var items3 = grossNGL2.Zip(seqNum2, (gngl, seq) => new { GNGL = gngl, Seq = seq }); //gngl STANDS FOR GROSS NGL

        //var olditems = ultOil.Zip(seqNum, (uoil, seq) => new { UOIL = uoil, Seq = seq });
        //var olditems2 = ultGas.Zip(seqNum, (ugas, seq) => new { UGAS = ugas, Seq = seq });

        foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) =>
        {
            double first = Convert.ToDouble(a.GOIL);
            double second = Convert.ToDouble(b.GGAS);
            double third = Convert.ToDouble(c.GNGL);
            double answer = first + third + (second / 6);
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", a.Seq, answer);
        }))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

If someone could tell me how to add the third array to the `foreach` loop that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the goal would be to add the c into the foreach loop

Comment: I think it needs to be outside of the first join so something like `items.Join(items2 ... ).Join(items3 ... )` should do what you want.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I tried doing this but the syntax is strange, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: What is the expected output after combining the data?

Comment: @RyanGates It would be the seqNum, the double answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For joins usually comprehensive (or query) syntax is easier:

```
var query = from i1 in items
            join i2 in items2 on i1.seq equals i2.seq
            join i3 in items3 on i1.seq equals i3.seq
            select new { i1, i2, i3 };

foreach(var x in query)
{
    double first = Convert.ToDouble(x.i1.GOIL);
    ....
```

Comment: To get the output would I just write sw.WriteLine(answer); then?